# How do I import registry settings using TeamCity?

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, registry, teamcity

I'm having trouble importing settings from a `.reg` file using TeamCity. The app in question has a lot of registry settings which change fairly regulary so it is vital to have it as a build step.

I'm using the following command:

```
regedit /s "C:\app\params\epm\epm_tlp\trunk\csr_vsm_tlp_exl.reg"
```

The path is fine (I checked several times). When I run this command manually, it works. However, when run from TeamCity, it doesn't seem to do anything. Here's the log:

```
[16:01:13]: Checking for changes
[16:01:16]: Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[16:01:16]: Checkout directory: C:\app
[16:01:16]: Updating sources: server side checkout... (1s)
[16:01:16]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Building incremental patch for VCS root: NEP-content
[16:01:18]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Repository sources transferred
[16:01:18]: Step 1/2
[16:01:18]: [Step 1/2] Using runner: simpleRunner
[16:01:18]: [Step 1/2] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script1107617910631593889.cmd
[16:01:18]: [Step 1/2] in directory: C:\app\params\epm\epm_tlp\trunk
[16:01:18]: [Step 1/2] C:\app\params\epm\epm_tlp\trunk>regedit /s "C:\app\params\epm\epm_tlp\trunk\csr_vsm_tlp_exl.reg"
[16:01:18]: [Step 1/2] Process exited with code 0
[16:01:18]: Step 2/2
[16:01:18]: [Step 2/2] Using runner: simpleRunner
[16:01:18]: [Step 2/2] Starting: c:\app\exe\startup.exe
[16:01:18]: [Step 2/2] in directory: C:\app\exe
[16:01:18]: [Step 2/2] Process exited with code -1073741515
[16:01:18]: [Step 2/2] Step failed
[16:01:18]: Publishing artifacts
[16:01:18]: [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [teamcity-info.xml]
[16:01:18]: [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
[16:01:18]: Build finished
```

This is the first time I'm trying out TeamCity, so I have no idea where to start looking for trouble, why would this command fail? Could there be any security causes? Are TeamCity runners running as another user?

Comment: Have you tried 'REG.EXE IMPORT' instead? Since it's a console application, it might output a useful error message.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: I did not try that, no. Currently I don't have the time to "play" with TC again, but when I do I'll try and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have TeamCity build agent running as a Windows service. Please make sure this windows service is run under windows account, which has sufficient privileges.

Comment: I have actually thought of this this morning, so I've checked it out. I've switched it from running as a system account to the administrator account and it didn't help :-/ One thing I don't understand is regedit exiting with code 0...shouldn't it fail?

Comment: Just to double check - did you change the user for TeamCity build agent service (and not TeamCity server service?)